# Why does Vim sometimes create .swp files?

Tags: vim

Sometimes Vim creates a .swp file when I edit something, but not always. Why is that, and what causes Vim to create .swp files? Is it bad to disable them in [.vimrc](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Open_vimrc_file)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vim creates `.swp` files [for recovery](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/recover.html). In case you fail to save, vim will be able to recover (at least some of) the file.

The merits of disabling them depends on what you do. If you use vim for anything that has a build, you probably save your sources all the time (how much time goes by between your coding stuff and compiling, building, and running a ut? Probably not hours). I hate the swps because they always require me to tell the version control system to ignore them.

Comment: You can centralize your `.swp` files easily by changing your `'dir'` setting. e.g. `set directory^=~/.local/vim/tmp//`. See `:h 'dir'` for more information.

Comment: Thanks, @PeterRincker, that's a good alternative. Did not know that.

Comment: If you care about recovery you should also set `undofile` and `undodir` to allow you to run `undo` across sessions.  Something like this: `set undofile undodir=~/.vim/undo undolevels=10000`. You can clean this directory periodically, f.i. I set these in crontab to run every day: `rm -f ~/.vim/undo/%tmp%* ~/.vim/undo/%var%tmp%*` and `find ~/.vim/undo -type f -mtime +30 -print0 | xargs -0 rm -f --`